# Recover an Asynch ThreadPoolTaskexecutor after server crashed/shut down

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, executor

I Have a Spring rest controller which is calling an asynchronous method using Spring's @Async methodology and return immediately an http 202 code (Accepted) to the client.(The asynchronous job is heavy and could lead to a timeout). 
So actually, at the end of the asynchronous task, i'm sending an email to the client telling him the status of his request.

Everything works just fine but I'm asking myself what can I do if my server/jvm crashes or if it is shut down?  My client would receive a 202 code and will never receive a the status email.

Is there a way to synchronize (in real time) a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in a database or even in a file to let the server recover at startup without managing this on my own with complex rules and evolution status?

Here is my Executor configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("asyncTaskExecutor-");
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(120);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(30);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

The controller that launch the async task

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testAsync", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void testAsync() throws InterruptedException{
    businessService.doHeavyThings();
}
```

The async method called:

```
@Async
public void doHeavyThings() throws InterruptedException {

    LOGGER.error("Start doHeavyThings with configured executor - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at " + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
    LOGGER.error("Stop doHeavyThings with configured executor - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at " + new Date());
}
```

}

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web server shutdown the application lifecycle in a java web application will notifiy a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). If you provide an implementation of a ServletContextListener you can put your 'what is already processed' logic in the `contextDestroyed` method.

When the web server or the application is started again the listener can be used to recover an re-process the unprocessed items of your job using the `contextInitialized` method.

Another option would be using [Spring destruction callbacks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) and place the logic here.

HTH